# Php errors: Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php

On my website show the following error:

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client2/web3/web:/var/www/clients/client2/web3/tmp:/var/www/zkus.eu/web:/srv/www/zkus.eu/web:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/clients/client2/web3/web/admin/login.php on line 4

Warning: include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client2/web3/web:/var/www/clients/client2/web3/tmp:/var/www/zkus.eu/web:/srv/www/zkus.eu/web:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/clients/client2/web3/web/libs/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 161
```

On website (ISP Config) show following errors:

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/lib/classes/session.inc.php on line 90 Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/lib/classes/session.inc.php on line 111 Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/lib/classes/session.inc.php on line 112 Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/lib/classes/session.inc.php on line 113
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: First step: Read what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem looks like you're including a file outside your permissions.  Maybe grabbing a file from a folder you do not own?

The second error can be fixed with an update to your .htaccess:

```
php_value date.timezone 'Europe/London'
```

Substitute Europe/London for your timezone. Find a supported timezone here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php