# Apache/PHP Timezone Warning

Tags: php, macos, apache, date, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Configuration: It is not safe to rely on the system’s timezone settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213608/php-configuration-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings)
>   [Php errors: Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345436/php-errors-warning-require-function-require-open-basedir-restriction-in-e)

My first question here at stackoverflow (please be nice :P)

## Why is my apache showing this error?

Severity: Warning

Message: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone  settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead

### Environment

I'm using MacOS Mountain Lion's (10.8.2) Apache.

### Things I've tried

- I've tried to rename my /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini but when I do, php won't compile anymore.
- I've also tried to uncomment this line (in the php.ini):

  date.timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'

But it doesn't do anything. As soon as I restart apache the php stops working.

#### Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php errors: Warning: require() \[function.require\]: open\_basedir restriction in effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345436/php-errors-warning-require-function-require-open-basedir-restriction-in-e). Also please see [So I need to restart Apache after changing the php.ini file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/so-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file)

Comment: Dear Rick please check : http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2012/03/19/setting-the-time-zone-for-php-5-3-x/ -- Your friend Google ;)

Comment: Also, if it causes PHP to "stop working", you should check your logs.

Comment: @Rick: If your problem is to locate the php.ini file that is in effect, please see `INFO_GENERAL` for the [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) function to locate it on your system.

Comment: @hakre The phpinfo shows **Configuration File (php.ini) Path = /etc** Right now I have /etc/php.ini.default

Comment: Check for loaded configuration files. That entry should name the concrete file name (not only a directory path). Also there might be a list of directories where it is checked in. For more information about PHP.ini files (there can be more than one), please see: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: @user868766 I did check google before posting :P  As a temporal solution I've added this line to my .htaccess **php_value date.timezone Europe/Berlin**

Comment: @Rick Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: @user868766less thanks. I'm still researching to find the php.ini solution, so I don't have to add that line to every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is PHP message, not Apache. And it is because, as messages indicates, of misconfiguration of your PHP. Edit your correct `php.ini` file (usually, it ends in `/etc/php5/<FLAVOUR>/php.init`, where "FLAVOUR" can be `apache2`, `cli` or (most likely) `cgi` (or `cgi-bin`), for example `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Then uncomment `date.timezone` line and put your timezone, i.e.

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: The quotes are fine. That does not cause the problem for the OP.

Comment: If so, then he is changing wrong `php.ini` file. Which my answer also covers.

Comment: As well as the many existing answers. And the "no quotes" hint is misleading btw.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. However, I don't have the /etc/php5 directory.

I do have /etc/apache2 but there's no php.ini there.